# How to simplify derivative of power of logarithm of function?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, logarithms

The logarithmic differential is famous $$\frac{\partial \log(f)}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{f(x)}\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$

If we instead consider $k$th derivative of $n$th power of logarithm of a function:

$$\frac{\partial^k (\log(f(x))^n)}{{\partial x}^k}$$

It quickly becomes more advanced expressions

It seems we do get terms with factors like $\frac{k!}{(k-m)!},m\leq n$, binomial coefficients(?),

$$\prod_{\forall l}{f^{(l)}(x)}^{k_l} , k=\sum_{\forall l} k_l$$
$$\frac{1}{f(x)^k}$$ and other nasty things.

---

Does there exist some nice trick or formula to try and simplify this expression we will get?

Comment: Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula)

Comment: Ah, I KNEW there was such a formula somewhere. I probably saw it on this site a year ago or two also. Thank you @Rumpelstiltskin .

Comment: Wow even number theory things like partitions are in there. Now this is starting to get exciting.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin feel free to make it an answer if you want to.